# If a website doesn't have an API - what to do?

Tags: objective-c

There is a website called:
Engrade.com.

It's pretty cool, you can monitor what your grades are in your current classes. But I want to make an objective-c app that can log in as me and get my grades. Then probably, it would alert me to any bad grades, etc.

Problem!!! It doesn't have an API, so I'm stuck. Does anyone know how I would do this?

Thanks,
Elijah

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always just download the page and parse it yourself - be warned that this approach is fraught with peril.  You can read about [web scraping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping) in general on Wikipedia.